# Spring AMQP: When using programmatic endpoint registration, how to set routing key?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I am using programmatic endpoint registration of listener endpoints:

```
MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint = new MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint();
endpoint.setId(endpointId);
endpoint.setQueues(eventsQueue);
endpoint.setBean(hanlderMethod.bean);
endpoint.setMethod(hanlderMethod.method);
endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory);
registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
```

My question is, how do I determine the routing key for this endpoint?

---

**Edit:** To further clarify, I am using a single queue for different types of messages, and I want to route them to different methods based on the routing key. This is in addition to the routing key used to route the messages to this queue to begin with.

Basically the use case is a general-purpose events bus. All the events go to the same exchange. Each type of event has a unique routing key. Each service has an events queue. Each service subscribes to the events it is interested in by adding the appropriate binding between the events exchange and its own events queue using the routing key for that event type. Each event type has a different handler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you say `Listener`, so you are going to listen some queue for messages.

And right, you do that via `setQueues()`.

Now regarding `routingKey`:

> The routing key is a message attribute. The exchange might look at this key when deciding how to route the message to queues (depending on exchange type).

So, it really doesn't relate to the `Listener`.

Although I agree that we should declare `Binding` exactly in that place when we deal with queue. Therefore in the listener part.

So, if you do `MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint` registration manually (bypassing `@RabbitListener` definitions), you should declare and register `Binding` manually, too. And already here with an appropriate `routingKey`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#_binding

**UPDATE**

There is no such a built-in feature which you are looking for.
We have `MultiMethodRabbitListenerEndpoint` who does the routing based on the payload type, but not any other possible filter.

What you want can be achieved with the Spring Integration router which can make the decision based on the `AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY` header.

From other side maybe that would be better to register unique queues for each `routing key` and have only one possible listener for that queue with appropriate method.

Comment: Yes I know about the declaration and I'm doing that too. The problem is that I want to route messages to different methods from the same queue based on the routing key.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: I went with the multiple queues solution, but it would be nice to add this ability as it will minimise the number of needed queues in this common scenario.

Comment: Well, you can even implement just regular `Listener` and make a route from it according the `MessageProperties.receivedRoutingKey` value.

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to implement all the deserializaiton and argument binding myself?

Comment: Yes, with the generic `Listener`, you have to. But you can still get a gain from the deserializaiton. You can just have one `RabbitListener` method with the `payload` and `@Header(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY)` as required arguments. Do the routing decision here and invoke an appropriate method with its arguments. I'd say that `Message` (or just `payload`) would be better choice for the target methods.